# data into datetime column does not inserted correctly while csv importing into database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, mysql2

I am creating a ruby on rails application. While importing date into available_on column, date does not inserted into database correctly.It's changes when I import data using csv file.

```
def import
  require 'csv'
  file = params[:file]
  CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
    @prod = Spree::Product.new()
    @prod.name = row["name"]
    @prod.shipping_category_id = row["shipping_category_id"]
    @prod.description = row["description"]
    @prod.available_on = row["available_on"]
    @prod.meta_description = row["meta_description"]
    @prod.meta_keywords = row["meta_keywords"]
    @prod.tax_category_id = row["tax_category_id"]
    @prod.shipping_category_id = row["shipping_category_id"]
    @prod.promotionable = row["promotionable"]
    @prod.meta_title = row["meta_title"]
    @prod.featured = row["featured"]
    @prod.supplier_id = row["supplier_id"]
    @prod.master.price = row["master_price"]
    @prod.master.cost_price = row["cost_price"]
    @prod.master.depth = row["depth"]
    @prod.master.height = row["height"]
    @prod.master.width = row["width"]
    @prod.master.weight = row["weight"]
    @prod.master.sku = row["sku"]
    @prod.master.tax_category_id = row["tax_category_id"]
    @prod.save!
  end 
end
```

my database table is just like:

```
| id                   | int(11)     
| name                 | varchar(255)
| description          | text        
| available_on         | datetime    
| deleted_at           | datetime    
| slug                 | varchar(255)
| meta_description     | text        
| meta_keywords        | varchar(255)
| tax_category_id      | int(11)     
| shipping_category_id | int(11)     
| created_at           | datetime    
| updated_at           | datetime    
| promotionable        | tinyint(1)  
| meta_title           | varchar(255)
| featured             | tinyint(1)  
| supplier_id          | int(11)
```

and I know this due to datatype of available_on.
and I inserted date into available_on is like '2015-10-10'. 
Can any one tell how to remove this inconsistency from database while importing csv file

Answer (score 1):

Use the `:converters` option to tell Ruby to automatically convert date fields:

```
require 'csv'

def import
  file = params[:file]

  CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true, converters: :date) do |row|
    # ...
  end 
end
```

P.S. Might I suggest cleaning this up a bit?

```
PRODUCT_ATTR_NAMES = %w[ name             shipping_category_id  description
                         available_on     meta_description      meta_keywords
                         tax_category_id  promotionable         meta_title
                         featured         supplier_id ]

MASTER_ATTR_NAMES = %w[ master_price  cost_price  depth  height
                        width         weight      sku    tax_category_id ]

def import
  require 'csv'
  file = params[:file]

  CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true, converters: :date) do |row|
    row = row.to_hash
    product_attrs = row.slice(*PRODUCT_ATTR_NAMES)
    master_attrs = row.slice(*MASTER_ATTR_NAMES)

    @prod = Spree::Product.create!(product_attrs) do |product|
      product.master.assign_attributes(master_attrs)
    end
  end 
end
```

Comment: when in my csv's available_on column have 15-12-2015, then it is inserted into database like this '2015-11-14 18:30:00'. Which is wrong and I want that will inserted like 15-12-2015 then time.IS it possible?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "then time," but this has to do with your locale settings. 2015-11-14 18:30:00 UTC is the same as 2015-11-15 00:00:00 UTC+0530. If UTC+0530 (India and Sri Lanka) is your time zone then it would appear that it was inserted correctly. You'll need to configure your application to display the dates in your preferred time zone.

Comment: config.time_zone = 'Kolkata'
config.active_record.default_timezone = :local
this is added in my config/application file but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You should parse the value into an instance of class `Time`:

```
require 'time'

@prod.available_on = Time.parse(row["available_on"])
```

You would most likely want to do some type conversion on other columns as well. Those that should contain integer values, for example:

```
@prod.tax_category_id = Integer(row["tax_category_id"])
```

Likewise for the other non-string values.

Comment: when I do this then it is showing error TypeError in "Spree::Admin::ProductsController#import" and "no implicit conversion of Date into String".how to remove this error.

Comment: Which line causes the TypeError?